# how to write conditional statements in ng-class?

Tags: angularjs

I have written the condition as

```
ng-class="{true: 'ion-ios-heart', false: 'ion-ios-heart-outline'}[favOffers[offer.id]]"
```

i.e if favOffers[offer.id] has a value then apply the class in true statement else apply the class in false statement.

But it is not working. favOffers is defined in my controller.

Comment: You cannot access a angular object like this. I imagine angular is not qualifying anything after the last `}` too. Is this being used inside an `ng-repeat`?

Comment: i think i am unable to access favOffers[offer.id] in my template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a ternary condition in your case

```
<div ng-class="favOffers[offer.id] ? 'ion-ios-heart': 'ion-ios-heart-outline'"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
<div ng-class="{'ion-ios-heart' : favOffers[offer.id], 'ion-ios-heart-outline' : !favOffers[offer.id] }>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `favOffers[offer.id]` is defined and it's not causing errors and you can use double `!!` to effort a boolean value in case of undefined like `ng-class="{true: 'ion-ios-heart', false: 'ion-ios-heart-outline'}[!!favOffers[offer.id]]"`.

For example, in the following code snippet there is no `isTrue` memeber defined, by doing `!!isTrue` it will always return false if it's not defined, finding the right value even if it's undefined.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    //$scope.isTrue = false;
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```css
.bg-green{
  background: green;
}

.bg-red{
  background: red;  
}

.bg-green,
.bg-red{
  padding: 2px 4px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isTrue" > <tt>isTrue</tt>
  <p>Main solution</p>
  <p ng-class="{ true: 'bg-green', false: 'bg-red' }[!!isTrue]">{ true: 'bg-green', false: 'bg-red' }[!!isTrue]</p>
  <p>Alternative solutions</p>
  <p ng-class="isTrue ? 'bg-green' : 'bg-red'">isTrue ? 'bg-green' : 'bg-red'</p>
  <p ng-class="{ 'bg-green': isTrue, 'bg-red': !isTrue }" >{ 'bg-green': isTrue, 'bg-red': !isTrue }</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try out directly with object value....here am assuming ion-ios-heart and  ion-ios-heart-outline as two classes defined somewhere.

```
ng-class="{'ion-ios-heart': offer.id!=='null', 'ion-ios-heart-outline': offer.id=='null'}"
```

try to configure object values according to your requirement.check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j4r8MDt3Q77NFJlhv7oQ?p=preview) once

Answer (score 1):

For the clarity and readability of the code why don't you use a method in your controller to make this check?

For example

```
   <div ng-class="{'className':isTestCondition(), 'className1':!isTestCondition()}"</div>
```

and then in your controller:

```
  $scope.testCondition = function() {}
```

There are different ways to check if an Array contains an object. You could find the different ways in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript) answer.